# When are the physical benefits of a single workout realized?

Tags: recovery, abdominals, muscle-recovery, anatomy, physiology

When does your body actually build muscle in response to fatigue from a workout?

For example, if you slam your arms in one work out ( say any combination of, curls, pullups, pushups, bench press, etc. ), will its effect on the size of your arms be immediately evident, or will they mostly grow during recovery?

Does it vary by muscle group?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this article](http://www.livestrong.com/article/406021-when-do-muscles-grow-after-working-out-with-weights/), Muscle growth starts about 1 hr after a workout and continues for up to 24 hours. It is important to have sufficient protein and slow release carbs to ensure maximum muscle synthesis.